# Insert new row every 2nd element of python list

Tags: python, csv

I have the following List

```
mylist = ['a','b','c' ....]

list.append('a')
list.append('b'+'\r\n')
list.append('c')
```

CSV Generate

```
with open(csvFile, "w",) as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter='\r\n')
    writer.writerow(list)
```

How do I ensure that a new row is inserted after every 2nd element ? By default `'\r\n'` is used as the lineterminator so I've tried to add `'\r\n'` add the end of every 2nd string when I build my list but no such luck, the csv is always generated all on one row.

Comment: How are you opening your CSV?

Comment: Why are you using `\r\n` as the *delimiter*? What is the expected output here?

Comment: Note: you **cannot** use a two character delimiter; your code won't even run now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you try to generate a csv file with two columns.

First structure your data to match the structure of the file. e.g.

```
mylist = [('a', 'b'), 
          ('c', 'd'),
           ... 
         ]
```

Then you can add the column and line separators.

```
'\n'.join( ','.join(row) for row in mylist )
```

If you also want the last line of the file to end in a '\n', use

```
''.join( ','.join(row) + '\n' for row in mylist)
```

However, as others suggest it is probably better to use the csv module, which also
takes care of quoting column separators etc.
Also when you use the csv module, i think it is much clearer if your data is structured
appropriately, i.e. as a list of rows.

By the way I use '\n' instead of '\r\n', because if you write to a file opend in text mode, python will replace '\n' by '\r\n' if it is the platform default (i.e. on Windows)

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is the right approach. I will structure each column as a separate list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *join* your strings with separators, then use `str.join()`:

```
'\r\n'.join(mylist) + '\r\n'
```

but you really want to use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to write CSV files:

```
import csv

with open(outputfilename, 'wb') as ofh:
    writer = csv.writer(ofh)
    for value in mylist:
        writer.writerow([value])
```

Note that `writerow()` expects a *list* of columns, so if each string in your input list is one row, wrap it in a list.

The CSV module uses `\r\n` as the line separator by default:

```
>>> import csv
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> ofh = StringIO()
>>> writer = csv.writer(ofh)
>>> writer.writerow(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> ofh.getvalue()
'a,b,c\r\n'
```

If you are trying to write every two values from your list as one row, then do so:

```
with open(outputfilename, 'wb') as ofh:
    writer = csv.writer(ofh)
    for i in range(0, len(mylist), 2):
        writer.writerow(mylist[i:i+2])
```

for a simple method, or generate your list to have a nested structure:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ...]
```

or write the rows *as you produce them*.

Comment: Personally, not a fan of the `csv` module. It's easier for me to do it myself than to remember the `Dialect` syntax.

Comment: @selllikesybok: Then you've never handled CSV with embedded newlines or quoted values.

Comment: @user3014073: The CSV module adds newlines **for you**. The CSV module by default uses `\r\n` as the line separator.

Comment: I am using the csv module. I've added more code example to my original post

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have. I just prefer to do it myself.

Comment: @selllikesybok: Really, the dialect keywords are but a tiny issue. The module handles quoting and newlines, but also whitespace stripping and on writing, conversion to string. Code using it is far more readable for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import csv

mylist=[chr(i) for i in range(65,86)]  #['A', 'B', ... 'T', 'U']

with open(ur_file,'w') as fout:
    writer=csv.writer(fout)
    for line in (mylist[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(mylist),2)):
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Makes a file like this:

```
A,B
C,D
E,F
G,H
I,J
K,L
M,N
O,P
Q,R
S,T
U
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]

for x in list:
with open(csvFile, "w",) as output:
    index = 0
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow(list[index:index + 2)
    # however many values you want to write as one line
    index += 2
```